# Subgroup of order 2 in the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\} $ for $p \equiv 1$ mod 4

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let p be a prime, $p \equiv 1$ mod 4 . $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\} $ contains a subgroup of order 2 whose preimage is a subgroup of order 4 in $ (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Question: What would be the subgroup of order 2 in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\}$?

The cosets in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\} $ are representatives $ \{\bar{1},\bar{2}, \bar{3}, ..., \overline{\frac{p-1}{2}}\} $ where $\bar{a} := a\{\pm1\}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Answer: $(\overline{\frac{p-1}{2}}!)$ is the subgroup of order 2 in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\}$, using Wilson's theorem. See @Jyrki Lahtonen 's comment.

Comment: Your statement about cosets is not correct no matter whether you mean the cosets of $\{1,-1\}$ or the cosets of the subgroup of order 4.

Comment: Are you allowed to know that there is a primitive root modulo $p$?

Comment: @Stephen Sry, I saw my mistake, should the above be correct now?

Comment: Hint: there is some $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ such that $a^2=-1$.

Comment: Your question doesn't compute. To ask about cosets one needs to be explicit about the group and its subgroup. Your question has a lot of groups and subgroups floating around. If you are talking about the cosets of $\{\pm1\}$  in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ they are $\{\pm1,\pm2, \pm3, ..., \pm \frac{p-1}{2}\}$ Note that all cosets are the same size and they partition the group. Now what is your question?

Comment: @Stephen I corrected my answer above which is close to the coset you described except I used the bar notation instead. Hence $\frac{p-1}{2}$ would be the coset of order 2. Thanks.

Comment: I think your question needs a full rewrite after the first sentence. There may be a decent question in there but it is obscured by too many mistakes and vague references.

Comment: @Stephen Rewrote it, thanks!

Comment: @rogerl Yes, ultimately, what this was trying to show is that given the unique residue class -1 is of order 2 in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ , the subgroup of order 4 in (Z/pZ)× is cyclic. I got mixed up with the wrong set of cosets in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\}$.

Comment: It is a fun exercise to prove that when $p\equiv1\pmod4$ the coset of $(\dfrac{p-1}2)!$ has order two in $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times/\{\pm1\}$. Knowing Wilson's theorem helps here.

Comment: @Jyrki You mean this is not possible, correct?

Comment: On the contrary. It is easy! It is not computationally helpful if $p$ is a large prime, because calculating that factorial modulo $p$ is a bit of a pain. But, if you want a "simple" formula for the non-trivial element in that subgroup of order two, then...

Comment: When $p=5$, $((p-1)/2)!=2!\equiv2\pmod 5$. With $p=13$  $((p-1)/2)!=6!=720\equiv5\pmod{13}$ et cetera.

Comment: @Jyrki Woah, thanks so you did mean $\frac{p-1}{2}$ factorial; I was testing on p =13 but I must have made a mistake; I looked at 5 mod 13 but thought the result should give me 1 while it was $5^{2} \equiv 1$ mod 13. But this is very cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup of order 2 must have 2 elements, one of which is the identity. If it were as you say, it would be $\{\bar1, \overline {\frac {p-1} {2}} \}$ but that is not true for $p=13$. in that case $(\bar 6)^2= \bar 3$ so the set isn't closed under multiplication. The right subgroup for $p=13$ is $\{\bar1, \bar 5\}$.

Comment: See the comment by @rogerl

Comment: So it really depends on p; for p = 5, (p-1)/2 = $\bar{2}$ is the element of order 2. Since 2 is a prime and the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\} $ is even, by Cauchy's theorem, there exists an element in the finite group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / \{\pm1\} $ of order 2.